# Check if value in 3 different date ranges in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery

I have a table `wp_posts` which contains `post_date` and `author_id` columns

I need to find the `author_id` from `wp_posts` where has posts in (all) 3 time ranges:

```
wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 23:59:59'
wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-17 23:59:59'
wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59'
```

Looks simple, but I can't figure out.
If I put AND between every date range, will always return 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put OR:

```
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 23:59:59') OR 
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-17 23:59:59') OR
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59')
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT author_id FROM wp_posts
WHERE author_id IN (
    SELECT author_id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 23:59:59'
) AND author_id IN (
    SELECT author_id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-17 23:59:59'
) AND author_id IN (
    SELECT author_id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59'
)
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Hello @SubRed. Actually a need the posts grouped by author_id which matches in all 3 date ranges. If I find a author_id which has posts in 1 date range, I need to ignore him, the same if fits in 2 date ranges. 
I need only if author_id has posts in all 3 date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author_ID
FROM posts
WHERE   (wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 23:59:59') OR
        (wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-17 23:59:59') OR
        (wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59')
GROUP BY author_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 23:59:59') or
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-17 23:59:59') or
(wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59')
```